# If $u=0$ in the border can I say $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}=0$ in the border?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

$$u(x) = \int_{\Omega} T_y(x)\Delta u(y) dy - \int_{\partial \Omega} u(y)\frac{\partial T_y(x)}{\partial \vec n} - T_y(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n} d\sigma(y)$$

If I have that $u=0$ in $\partial \Omega$ then can I say that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}=0$$

in $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Nope, it is not true in general. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, take $u(x) = |x|^2-1$, and $\Omega = B(0,1)$, the ball centered in zero with radius 1.

Comment: @Hugo how should I take this derivative in the border? In the interior I can have directions but in the border it's complicated

Comment: In general, $\partial u / \partial \vec{n} = \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}$, where $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product.

Comment: @hugo but to take the gradient I must have directions, and I don't have them in the border. Any direction gets out of the border

Comment: You can take the gradient in an interior point, and then take the limit as the point gets to the boundary.